# How to install All ERPNext Modules OR List of All Modules?

Tags: erpnext, frappe

Is there any way to download and install once all the ERPNext modules on my site? (HRMS, Payments, POSAwesome, Education, etc., etc.

what is know, this is doable by different lines of command (mentioned below) but I am not aware from all module names and their's commands. From where I can get all module names and their commands to install?

**COMMAND LINES FOR EACH SINGLE MODULE**

*ERPNext VERSION-15*

-----For ERPNext Module-----

```
bench get-app erpnext --branch version-15
bench --site mysite.com install-app erpnext
```

-----For Payments Module-----

```
bench get-app payments --branch version-15
bench --site mysite.com install-app payments
```

-----For HRMS Module-----

```
bench get-app hrms --branch version-15
bench --site mysite.com install-app hrms
```

-----For CRM Module-----

```
bench get-app CRM
bench --site mysite.com install-app CRM
```

----- so on… -----